# Novel where a woman is able to shake off mind control due to a broken microwave

Tags: story-identification, novel, mind-control

I read this about 5 years ago, as part of a series. I remember the main character was an investigator, I think of the private variety. He was a fairly grounded individual, but over the course of the books, he ran into multiple strange events and people, which all culminated in some sort of Lovecraftian conspiracy. A woman he was working with was, unbeknownst to him, under the influence of the conspiracy, with them able to peek into her mind and control her thoughts and actions. She realizes she's had brief moments of mental clarity where she shook of the control that seem to be tied to when she's operating her microwave. I think the door hinge was damaged, meaning it didn't properly shield the radiation from the magnetron, and that interfered with the mind control signal.

Somewhere near the end of the book, she runs the microwave in an even more blatantly damaged fashion to get a longer respite, and arranges am accident, I think involving a propane tank, that kills her and agents of the conspiracy, allowing her to at least die free. I think she had a chance to explain the mind control to the protagonist shortly before she admits to the impending explosion, giving him a chance to get away.

Thinking back on it, I think she was someone important from his past, maybe even estranged family, which made her death all the more poignant.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this is the book [Hosts](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/219402.Hosts), which is the fifth book of F. Paul Wilson's [Repairman Jack](https://www.goodreads.com/series/40868-repairman-jack) series.

The possessed girl is Jack's sister *Kate*, and the possession is by a virus called *Unity* that has a kind of hive mind. As you say she is temporarily freed when she uses the microwave though it's Kate's friend Jeanette who is first possessed:

> Jeanette didn’t look at her as she placed her cup inside the microwave and started jabbing the buttons. “What’s wrong—couldn’t see enough through the keyhole?”
>
> That stung. “Darn it, Jeanette, that’s not fair! I’m not snooping on you!”
>
> Jeanette turned toward her with a sneer twisting her lips, but then her whole expression changed, flashing from smugness to wide-eyed terror.
>
> “Kate, oh please, Kate, help me!” she cried, staggering forward against the counter and gripping it with white-knuckled intensity.

And as you say it's because the microwave door is cracked and leaking microwaves:

> He set the oven for five minutes and started it, then ran the little tester along the edges of the door. The indicator started flashing red immediately and went into high gear when he reached the lower right corner with the cracked glass.
>
> “That confirms it. Leaky oven.”

But at the end Kate constructs a bomb to destroy the virus. There is a propane tank explosion but this is caused by the bomb:

> She froze her emotions as she picked up the alarm clock. Its two detonator caps dangled on their crudely anastomosed wires against her thighs as she set the timer for 10 P.M. The time was a guess, but an educated one. She’d gleaned enough from the Unity to know that its new meeting place was not close by, and that the mutation to an airborne strain would not be a few minutes’ work. She assumed—prayed—she’d be in their midst by then.
>
> She carefully reinserted the detonators into the holes they’d previously occupied, then emptied her shoulder bag and gently settled the assembly into its bottom. A dishcloth from the sink covered the bomb, then the rest of her stuff went back in on top.

Comment: That's the one. Thank you. I might have to give that series a reread.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots The *Repairman Jack* books are good fun but they won't be winning the Man-Booker prize any time soon.

Comment: That was the first Jack book I read.  I've read them all since.